# Create a secure application with basicHttpBinding

Tags: wpf, wcf, authentication, certificate, basichttpbinding

I am really really tired these day because of facing this problem.
I am building a XBAP application (WPF Browser Application) that uses WCF Service.
This app requires:

- Users can login by using their username and password (that store in my database)
- **Users don't need to install any of X509 certificate (*.pfx or *.cert...)**
- The WCF service must use basicHttpBinding (to support an other silverlight application)

I have tried a lot of way but they are not match these requirements.
Do you have any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basicHttpBinding is - as its name implies - very basic in what it offers. It's especially basic when it comes to security.

As far as I know, you cannot achieve what you're trying to do. BasicHttpBinding only supports transport security (using https protocol) with Windows credentials (not suitable over Internet with custom users) or digital certificates, or message security by means of a digital certificate (which you explicitly rule out - why??).

Check this CodeProject article [8 steps to enable windows authentication on WCF BasicHttpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFBasicHttpBinding.aspx) or Google for "basicHttpBinding security" - you'll find lots of articles, but probably no real solution for your requirements - you just cannot do this with basicHttpBinding.

**Update:** by default in WCF, you should pass the caller's credentials with every call - but not as parameters on the service method, but instead by specifying the client credentials on the service proxy generated client-side. Something like:

```
 myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
 myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "p@ssw0rd";
```

Comment: One more question, pls. I want to build a silverlight application which allows user to login using WCF service (usernames and passwords are stored in database). Is it possible?

Comment: WCF services are (and should be) by nature stateless, e.g. you don't "login" and then use additional services. You provide your credentials with every call.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it means that WCF service required username and password for every call --> like this: "string getData(string username, string password, string keyword_to_get_data)" ??? :|

Comment: No, not really - you would pass the username/password as the client credentials in the header. You don't need to up them as parameters into your service calls.

Comment: And how to get username and password at server side (without using wsHttpBinding because silverlight only supports basicHttpBinding and netTCPBinding)?

Comment: You don't have to "get" those on the server side - the server side will be configured to validate those against e.g. ASP.NET membership database

Comment: Can you give me an example. Anyway, thank you very much. :)
P/S: I am using wsHttpBinding with a custom username validator. But it makes me confuse when trying to use basicHttpBinding.